# ASCII-like unicode characters in chat

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Occasionally (i.e., about 10-20 times in the last 1.5 years) I see players joining the server who appear to be using non-standard characters in their messages. I've been trying to identify the method those players are using, but I haven't managed to find any real lead.

[image: Chat screenshot]
As you can see I am using standard unicode display for chat messages. Chat logs display the message as `[LSL] JTheStr95: ????????? ??? ?????????`.

They are answering questions rather quickly using this font, I have therefore eliminated the possibility of copy/pasting every character from a list.
About a year ago I was able to verify that everyone using these characters (over the course of multiple months) was sending messages with the same set of characters. Creating a custom keyboard layout with such Unicode characters shouldn't be too difficult, but I don't think it explains the fact that so many independent players use the same character set without any variation.
I have tried searching the Unicode tables to identify the symbols - especially the unusually long underscore - but I have been unable to find the exact characters.
It also appears to be toggleable - some of the players immediately returned to normal ASCII characters after being requested to stop it.

I am a member of a Spigot server, but this has (once) happened on an unmodified server as well.
**Are there any known ways to reproduce this behavior?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They appear to be using  ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ  ｕｎｉｃｏｄｅ  ｃｈａｒａｃｔｅｒｓ．These are intended for when latin characters need to be used together with Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters, since they match the spacing of other glyphs. Keyboard drivers in these countries can often produce fullwidth Unicode characters directly.

There's several generators for these online, for example:

- [http://www.linkstrasse.de/en/ｆｕｌｌｗｉｄｔｈ－ｃｏｎｖｅｒｔｅｒ](http://www.linkstrasse.de/en/%EF%BD%86%EF%BD%95%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%97%EF%BD%89%EF%BD%84%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%88%EF%BC%8D%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%8E%EF%BD%96%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%92%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%92)
- http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi?text=hawai_5_o+say+something
- https://lingojam.com/FullWidthTextGenerator
- http://txtn.us/text-fullwidth
- http://fsymbols.com/generators/wide/

They can be pasted into Minecraft and appear as you are seeing:

[image]